# .htaccess Redirect issues

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, 301-redirect

This is what I need to do.

Redirect `sub1.domain1.co.uk` to `sub2.domain2.com`

Redirect `sub2.domain2.com` to `sub2.domain2.com/sub-folder`

These both work BUT this doesn't:

Navigating directly to `sub1.domain1.co.uk/sub-folder` does not redirect to `sub2.domain2.com/sub-folder`.

Here are my redirects:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://sub2.domain2.com/sub-folder

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1.domain1.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) sub2.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: In which folder is the .htaccess?

Comment: root directory of wordpress install

Comment: Do all these domains/subdomains point to the same place on the filesystem? How are you performing the first two redirects? I think it would be easier if you posted your entire .htaccess in your question, since the order of these directives is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of potential issues which could explain why one works and one does not...

1. You are mixing mod_alias (`RedirectMatch`) and mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) directives for external redirects. Different modules execute at different times during the request and work independently. This can result in confusing conflicts. If you are using mod_rewrite then it is safer to use mod_rewrite throughout.
2. You are using WordPress. So, you have existing mod_rewrite directives that route the request. Any external redirects must come *before* any WP routing directives.

> `RewriteRule (.*) sub2.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

You are also missing the scheme (ie. `http://`) from the substitution, so this will be seen as *relative* and break.

So, the following should come *before* any existing WordPress directives, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Redirect sub2.domain2.com/ to sub2.domain2.com/sub-folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =sub2.domain2.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://sub2.domain2.com/sub-folder [R=301,L]

# Redirect sub1.domain1.co.uk/<anything> to sub2.domain2.com/<anything>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =sub1.domain1.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://sub2.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would you suggest I handle the redirection for the sub2.domain2.com/ to sub2.domain2.com/sub-folder if not by RedirectMatch method?

Comment: Your current `RedirectMatch` method simply redirects a request for the document root, regardless of the host. I assume all these domains/subdomains to the same place? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve - what you say "works" could not possibly work with the code you have posted. So, presumably you have other redirects? I've updated my answer; you'll need an additional `RewriteRule` directive.

Comment: Note also, that you will need to clear your browser cache (or test with caching disabled) since any erroneous 301s will have been cached by the browser. Or you can use 302 (temporary) redirects initially and change to 301s later. (Incidentally, your `RedirectMatch` directive above is a 302.)

Comment: I used http://www.redirect-checker.org/ and http://redirectcheck.com/ to check and everything seems to be redirecting as required. Do you have any recommendations on other testing tools?